# How do you use a dependency of other package in your code?

Tags: rust, dependencies, rust-cargo, toml

I want to use a uuid dependency that is used in sqlx.

```toml
//! ./Cargo.toml

sqlx = { version = "0.6", default-features = false, features = [
    "chrono",
    "macros",
    "migrate",
    "postgres",
    "runtime-tokio-rustls",
    "uuid",
  ] }
uuid = { features = ["v4", "fast-rng"] }
```

I assume, that this version below will download seperate version of uuid for my project.

```toml
uuid = { features = ["v4", "fast-rng"], version = "1.4.1" }
```

Do I need to use this to take dependency of sqlx?

```toml
uuid = { features = ["v4", "fast-rng"], version = "*" }
```

Comment: Since you depend on a specific version of sqlx, just copy the version of uuid it depends on?

Comment: @Masklinn `"0.6"` is [any version `>=0.6.0` and `<0.7.0`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html#specifying-dependencies-from-cratesio), and any version in that range can change it's dependency on `uuid` (only in a non braking way though).

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the version `sqlx@0.6` depends on is `uuid@1.4.1` the first version

```toml
uuid = { features = ["v4", "fast-rng"], version = "1.4.1" }
```

i.e. copying the version string from the `Cargo.toml` of `sqlx` is the correct way to specify the same version, `cargo` will only download a single instance of a crate if all dependencies resolve to the same version of it.

```toml
uuid = { features = ["v4", "fast-rng"], version = "*" }
```

does not specify "use whatever another requirement specifies", that's just cargos default behaviour if 2 dependencie ranges for the same package overlap, it's use any version. (It's [equivalent to `">=0.0.0"`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html#wildcard-requirements)). It can arbitrarily break if any dependency of yours resolves to a version incompatible to the one used by `sqlx`.

There is no way to depend on a dependencies dependency version.

What crates do instead is reexport the crates they use and that's no different for `sqlx` `sqlx::types::uuid` is a [reexport of `uuid`](https://docs.rs/sqlx-core/latest/src/sqlx_core/types/mod.rs.html#34) (well it's a reexport of `sqlx_core::types::uuid`, but that then is `uuid` reexported)

So if you want to use the same type, you can add `use sqlx::types::uuid;` to your source instead of adding `uuid` to your `Cargo.toml`.

Comment: If I dont specify version in toml and use sqlx::types::uuid: ```dependency (uuid) specified without providing a local path, Git repository, version, or workspace dependency to use. This will be considered an error in future versions```. Looks like I need to use features and version="*" to be hyper correct

Comment: @gadzbi123 You should not specify `uuid` in your `Cargo.toml` at all when you use the reexport. That's why I wrote *"instead"*.